# Correlate passed time with time step size

Tags: time-series, correlation

Imagine a data set you might get from races in multiple laps.
For each race you'd have at what point in time a particular lap was completed (and equivalently begun) or, equivalently, how long it took the racer to complete each lap. (Both kinds of data are easily derivable from each other, obviously.)
Beyond that, there are no extra measurements. Note that this also means irregular intervals. And if that is important, the chosen race track doesn't have to be consistent over time either. So for some races laps will inherently be longer, just because the track is different. But I have no data on specifics of the track, beyond possibly previous runs of the same or maybe other racers for that track.

Now given such a data set, I'd like to measure the correlation between how long it took to complete a lap and how long the race has lasted thus far. - It's supposed to be a proxy for the change in racer concentration across a race.

Is there an inherently best choice for picking a certain point in time against which I might measure lap duration correlation? For this purpose I could choose the beginning of a round or its end or any interpolated point in between. - In actual fact, some catastrophic event which might significantly change lap time (temporarily losing control of a vehicle) could happen at any time in between. So since I don't have that information directly in the data, can I do some best guessing somehow? Or how else might I best go about this?

Comment: I don't know if there's a "best" choice for picking a certain point but, intuitively, they should be the same for both metrics: race and lap duration. I argue for the beginning of the race for race duration and the beginning of the lap for lap duration. I would also like to note information that could be incorporated beyond "no extra measurements." For instance, *track* constitutes an important factor that should condition any eventual answer. You also mention "multiple drivers." Is it possible to identify them in your data as a driver skill factor (individual differences in concentration)?

Comment: Ahh oops. I actually mentioned multiple drivers at first but actually wanted to remove that later and overlooked a mention.  The thing with multiple racers is that they need not always exist. Sometimes the data would be of training runs only coming from a single driver. Eventually more kinds of data might be possible but right now all I have is time stamps of completing a lap.

Comment: Ok...is it possible to add a feature which distinguishes between *training* and actual *race* laps?

Comment: That should be easily possible but would mean different answers for both cases, I assume. In actual races, from this data I could also infer whether, between laps, a racer has changed their current position relative to to another and also how often they might have been lapsed. I automatically get more timestamps. However, I don't get absolute position of all racers at each timestamp. Only ordering information and also only of the person who finished the lap relative to all others.

Comment: I can also separate which race track was done at a time and could from that, for instance, normalize time by dividing my data for each track by average time taken on this track either just for this driver or across all drivers.

Comment: *Different answers* between the two types of laps is an important control factor. *Current position* and *lapping* strike me as potentially useful information with which to condition a model but I wouldn't let it complicate the fundamental structure needed to answer the question you posed regarding lap length, race duration and driver focus.

Comment: I just reread your first reply and I think you might have mistook what I am asking. What I really would like to see is how much of the irregularities in lap lengths can be explained by how long the race has been going on. The reason for this question is that in a long race, after a while, racers' concentration drops - at leadt they themselves say so - so I wondered whether this is visible in the data.

Comment: Right. To me this suggests that careful specification of your target or response variable is at least as useful as defining the metrics used for the predictors to obtain the answer you want.